# How to make JavaFX TableView cells editable?

Tags: javafx-2, tableview

There are a lot of tutorials, And a lot of suggestions to achieve this by extending JavaFX cells to make them editable. A good one is [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880494/tableview-better-editing-through-binding/7884249#7884249).
But the [official tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CJAGDAHE) uses a method call to create the callback without writing all that code, By calling

```
lastNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

However when I do this in my code (FormTokens is my "model"):

```
// At beginning of class declaration
@FXML private TableColumn<FormTokens, String> valuColumn;

// Later at initialization
valuColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

Compiler says:

> The method 
>   setCellFactory(
>   `Callback<TableColumn<FormTokens,String>,TableCell<FormTokens,String>>)` 
>   
>  in the type `TableColumn<FormTokens,String>` 
>   
>  is not applicable for the arguments 
>   `(Callback<TableColumn<Object,String>,TableCell<Object,String>>)`

If I remove the method call mentioned above everything works well except that TableView cells are not editable. What am I doing wrong?

edit: I just found this: [Javafx TableView can not be edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895517/javafx-tableview-can-not-be-edited) But there are no solutions. How do I cast `Callback<TableColumn<Object,...` to `Callback<TableColumn<FormTokens,...`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Specify the exact type explicitly for generic parameter as

```
valuColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<FormTokens>forTableColumn());
```

Comment: It didn't require for me. I guess some error has been fixed in new JavaFX library.